# Weird problem when i try to format string to date in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to format string to Date.

```
this.deadLine = new Date(this.deadLine);
```

When I console this I got "Invalid Date".

The output of this.deadLine without a format is:

```
"2019-10-21T21:00:00.000Z"
```

If I do it without a variable like this its work:

```
const a = new Date("2019-10-21T21:00:00.000Z")
console.log (a)
```

The output good

```
Tue Oct 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Israel Daylight Time)
```

Why its not work on this.deadLine in the first line???

The Full Components:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Report } from 'src/app/shared/entity/report.entity';
import {Utils} from '../../../../shared/utils';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kit-header',
  templateUrl: './kit-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kit-header.component.sass']
})
export class KitHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() reportData: Report;
  public dateCreate: string;
  public year: String;
  public deadLine;
  public typeName: String;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('dateCreate') === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('dateCreate', JSON.stringify(this.reportData.dateCreated));
      localStorage.setItem('year', JSON.stringify(this.reportData.year));
      localStorage.setItem('deadLine', JSON.stringify(this.reportData.deadLine));
      localStorage.setItem('typeName', this.reportData.name);
      this.dateCreate = localStorage.getItem('dateCreate');
      this.year = localStorage.getItem('year');
      this.deadLine = localStorage.getItem('deadLine');
      this.typeName = localStorage.getItem('typeName');
    } else {
      this.dateCreate = localStorage.getItem('dateCreate');
      this.year = localStorage.getItem('year');
      this.deadLine = localStorage.getItem('deadLine');
      this.typeName = localStorage.getItem('typeName');
    }
    this.deadLine = new Date(this.deadLine);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I edit the post

Comment: Where do you call `this.deadLine = new Date(this.deadLine);`?

Comment: Inside ngOnInit i edit the post again

Comment: Before the last line in the `ngOnInit()` what is the value of `this.deadLine`?

Comment: the value is "2019-10-21T21:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce your error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.deadLine` is a string and you are trying to assign a `Date`.

To avoid this, the best thing is to declare the variable with a type: `public deadLine: Date;`

The problem itself is related to `JSON.stringify()`.

When you read the value, you should parse it:

```
new Date(JSON.parse(this.deadLine));
```

Comment: When i take date from local storage is string

Comment: That is the problem. You first assign a string value and then you try to assign a Date.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. First the *type* of deadLine is `any`, after the "supposedly" *string* assignment its *type* would be `string` and finally after Date conversion it would be `object`.

Comment: @NicholasK As you said, it's probably unrelated but it's more clear when you don't change the type. I will update the answer

Comment: Your edit won't work as `deadLine` is a *string* and **not** a json.

Comment: I think @NikNik is right here, if you are stringifying your date to store it, you need to JSON.parse it to use it. I have just tried this in console with and without parsing and i get `Invalid Date` if i don't parse it. I would maybe parse your `localStorage.getItem('deadLine');` sio you can reuse the correct value.